# How to transfer list as a parameter to query in Entity Framework?`

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Please help solve my problem.

I want get all strings with required id. I have a list with id.

Example = [1,2,3,4,5]

Query:

```
db.Sites.Where(c => c.Id == /*{get list this}*/)
        .Select(c => c.Name)
        .FirstOrDefault()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341422(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
var list=new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5};
var query= db.Sites.Where(c => list.Contains( c.Id)).Select(c => c.Name);
```

Comment: Big thanks. This is work.

Comment: you're welcome, glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
db.Sites.Where(c => list.Contains(c.Id)).Select(c => c.Name).ToArray();
```

This should return all the names as an array with matching Ids in the list.